# Angularjs - ui-select multiple selects the choices in the last loop

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

So, I have ui-selection with multiple selection under a loop.
Everything is fine, but when I select the choices, the match is displayed in the last loop , I'm not sure why it is happening as I do see two ui-select rendered.

My plunker is below, please can anyone help me debug
https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/smvnDVHcBAchNNOl